# How does The Pirate Bay get to keep its .org domain name?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, legal, top-level-domains, cctld

**.Org** TLD is maintained by a US based registry and US Feds are known to seize domains for torrent websites (Eg: Kickass Torrents old domains). But TPB is one of the most well known and oldest torrent sites and they seem to be able to run it on a **.org** while, much less popular and less scrutinized sites keep on jumping from one exotic ccTLD to another.